# variable value to use as javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have following code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var arr= new Array('10');


arr[0]='Need For Guru';
arr[1]='Qualities of a Guru';
arr[2]='Living Guru';
arr[3]='Who is a Satguru?';
arr[4]='Guru and Spiritual master';
arr[5]='Definition of discipleship';
arr[6]='Power of Faith';
arr[7]='Bad mouthing a Guru';
arr[8]='Fake Guru Shishya';
arr[9]='Pitfalls in the path of liberation';


var text='['+arr[0]+',\''+arr[1]+'\','+arr[2]+',\''+arr[3]+'\','+arr[4]+',\''+arr[5]+'\','+arr[6]+',\''+arr[7]+'\','+arr[8]+',\''+arr[9]+'\']';
document.write(text);

activatables('section', text );

</script>
```

My problem is that I want to use `value` of `text` as part of javascript code in line ---
`activatables('section', text );` .. so that code becomes like below

```
    activatables('section', ['Need For Guru','Qualities of a Guru',...]);
```

But I am not able to do the same.. .can anyone help in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are getting at... Do you want to serialize the array as text, and deserialize text into a new array?

To turn it into a string...

```
var arr = ["Need for a Guru", "Qualities of a Guru" /*, etc... */ ];
var text = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

To turn the string into an array...

```
var text = '["Need for a Guru", "Qualities of a Guru"]';
var arr = JSON.parse(text);
activatables('section', arr);
```

Obviously you don't need to deserialize / parse the text if you already have access to the source variable... You can just plug it straight in.

```
var arr = ["Need for a Guru", "Qualities of a Guru" /*, etc... */ ];
activatables('section', arr);
```

Comment: actually activatables function doesnot work if I pass variable. It works only if I specify static values as ..  activatables('section', ['Need For Guru','Qualities of a Guru',...]);  ... any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: i am sorry.. it got solved.. it was due to '?' character the activatables() was not working... thx for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this? If you want a string representation of your array, use:

```
JSON.stringify(arr);
```

Which can be passed as an argument using:

```
activatables('section', JSON.stringify(arr) );
```

However, in your case it seems you want to pass the string `section` and the array *itself* as arguments to the function `activatables`. If this is the case, all you need to do is:

```
activatables('section', arr );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
activatables('section', ['Need For Guru','Qualities of a Guru',...]);
```

means you're passing an array to `activatables`. With your current code you get that effect by passing `arr`, which is the array you want:

```
activatables('section', arr);
```

Comment: when page loads, my code should have arr evaluated as ... activatables('section', ['Need For Guru','Qualities of a Guru',...]); ... then only this works